# How does a computer distinguish the bits of a null terminator from an integer of 0?

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to understand the binary representation for `'\0'` vs the binary representation of `int 0` in C

if `'\0'` is a char. 1 byte of zeros in binary is: `00000000` ?

if 0 is an int. 4 bytes of zeros in binary is: `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`?

**1.** is my above understanding correct?

**2.** if so, how is the first byte of an int not confused with a null terminator?

**Note:** *I understand `NULL` is a pointer in C. I am not referring to pointers here.*

Comment: They cannot be distinguished. One is `zero` in `int` format, the other is `0` in `char` format. If you write to a `char array[]` with `array[0] = 0` the result is exactly the same as `array[0] = '\0'`

Comment: Bytes don't have any meaning, it's up to you to use them in accordance with what you think they're supposed to mean.

Comment: So if you had a pointer to an array of integers, how is the end of that array determined? Is that not what the null terminator is meant to signify?

Comment: There is no convention for an `int` array: the convention is for a `char` array and on that basis library functions that handle "strings" work. You *can* mark an `int` array with any kind of end marker you please (provided it does not appear in the array data), or you can keep track of the number of elements

Comment: so is it a fair assumption to say that there is no way to check the length of an array of `int`s ? (unless of course with a custom marker as you suggested)

Comment: @Chris that is typically so: if you pass a int pointer to a function as with `myfun(int *arr)` which you want to use as an array, there is no built in mechanism whereby the function can know the length of that array: it only knows the pointer and can index it however it pleases - subject to seg-fault!

Comment: @Chris: Arrays in C do not store any metadata about their length.  Note that the `0` terminator for strings only tells you the length of the string; it tells you nothing about the size of the array in which that string is stored. For example, if I wrote `char word[100] = "cat";`, there's no way for me to determine the actual size of the array (`100`) based on the length of the string (`3`).  You have to do your own bookkeeping on array sizes.

Comment: "so is it a fair assumption to say that there is no way to check the length of an array of `int`s ?"  Yes and no.  If it is an array of static or automatic duration whose declaration is in scope, then the compiler knows its length, and you can access it as `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.  That works for arrays of any element type.  You cannot do that with a pointer to the first element of the array however -- C array *representation* does not inherently contain information about the array length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. is my above understanding [of the representation of various `int` and `char` values] correct?

Pretty much.  The `char` value represented in C source code as `(char)'\0'` has numeric value zero and an all-zeroes representation in memory.  That representation is 8 bits in size on all modern machines, but C does not mandate that particular size, and some historic machines indeed did use different sizes.

Note also that as @mch observed, without any cast, the expression `'\0'` has type `int`.  It can be converted to type `char` without an explicit cast, as indeed happens when, for example, you assign it to a variable of that type.

> 2. if so, how is the first byte of an int not confused with a null terminator?

If your program is in a position to interpret the first byte of an `int` as if it were the representation of a `char` then its behavior is undefined.  Otherwise, it knows that the first byte is part of an `int` because that's what it assigned to that location.  There is no inherent distinction between the representation of the `char` value `(char)'\0'` and a suitably-aligned sequence of the same number of zero bits as part of the representation of an object of another type.

Comment: `'\0'` is not a `char` in C, it is an `int`, so it has all `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` bits set to zero.

Comment: @mch, my apologies for the imprecision in my exposition.  I have added the casts needed to make the embedded C expressions of which you speak have type `char`.

Answer (score 2):

**1. is my above understanding correct?**

yes

---

**2. if so, how is the first byte of an int not confused with a null terminator?**

There is nothing to be confused about.

If the variable itself is `int` then `sizeof(int)` bytes are fetched, and if all are `0`s, then the value is `0`.

If the variable is `char` then `sizeof(char)`, bytes are fetched and if all are `0`s then it is interpreted as `\0` `NUL` character.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is not probably `1`, it is guaranteed by the C standard to be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

They cannot be distinguished. One is zero in `int` format, the other is zero in `char` format. If you write to a `char array[]` with

```
array[0] = 0;
```

the result is exactly the same as

```
array[0] = '\0';
```